# Binding a collection of data to objects (not using a ListBox!) in WP7/Silverlight

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an observable collection of objects that I'd like to display on the screen, but not in a listbox format. For the sake of example, let's say that they're an observable collection of planets and I'd like to display them on the screen as they appear in the sky. Is this something I can do neatly in Silverlight binding? At the moment I'm thinking of just looping through my planet collection and creating an ellipse object for each, but it would be great if I could do this via data binding instead.

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible and there is a great [example from Bea Stollnitz](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=40) that demonstrates the power of xaml and styling. It's an old post (5 years! wow) but still well worth the read as are her other blogs

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=40